# IDEA dock window layout

Tags: configuration, intellij-idea, docking

Is it possible to change the way that docked tool windows in IDEA are laid out?

Currently, the bottom most window takes all the horizontal space, and the left and right windows do not take all the vertical space (because of the bottom window).

Is it possible to arrange the layout so that the left and right docked windows take all the vertical space, and the bottom one takes what's left over?

I.e. to have this:

```
+-----+---------------------------+-----+
|Tree |                           |Tree |
|     | Code                      |     |
|     |                           |     |
|     |                           |     |
|     |                           |     |
|     |---------------------------|     |
|     | Messages                  |     |
|     |                           |     |
+-----+---------------------------+-----+
```

Instead of this:

```
+-----+---------------------------+-----+
|Tree |                           |Tree |
|     | Code                      |     |
|     |                           |     |
|     |                           |     |
|     |                           |     |
+-----+---------------------------+-----+
| Messages                              |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18948518/656912) is now the correct answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This feature is available since IntelliJ IDEA 13 release.

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Appearance & Behavior` | `Appearance` | **Widescreen tool window layout**.

[image: widescreen layout]

---

Obsolete original answer:

No, such configuration is not supported at the moment, feel free to [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: @Shorn, it's already [implemented in IDEA 13](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74140#comment=27-510653).

Answer (score 9):

IDE Settings > Appearance > Widescreen tool window layout

Comment: No idea this existed - but awesome!!! Now I can better use the Favorites panel. With changesets always open there was not enough room before.

Comment: @daveb. I'd suggest marking Mason Lee's as the correct answer.