# How to modify IntelliJ views layout

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ (2017.X) default layout is like below:

[image: Default layout]

How to make it as this:

[image: New layout]

Is that even possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible, only both tools windows can take the full vertical size as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4248134/104891.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's really annoying.